# How to access the modal popup placed in content page from Master page control?

Tags: html, asp.net

I am creating a website using ASP.NET and it consists a master page, I have a login link on this master page so that it is available for all the content pages. Now I want the login page to be opened as a modal popup, so I wrote the code for modal popup in login page's aspx file. But I don't know how to access that modal popup placed on login content page from that login link that is present on master page so that the modal can be open at any page whenever i click on the login link??
Can anyone help me?
I have attached the screen shots of master page and login page and highlighted the concerned parts.
Thank you
[First image is of login content page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Ds6.png)

[Second image is of Master page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzPSk.png)

Answer (score 0):

could you not add an on click event to the login link or capture the event with jquery?
It looks like your using bootstrap, so what about adding this bit of JS.

$('#LoginModal').modal('show');

You can then give each input a name or ID on the login modal, the capture it by serialising the login form on button click.